# Powershell: How to loop through a list of calendar objects and match the returns against a .csv containing mulitple values

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, foreach, exchange-server

Here is the scenario: I need to identify when conference rooms have a VIP attending so we can send a tech to make sure the room is working properly beforehand. I know there a many ways to do this, but since our list of VIPs is only about a hundred or so, I think it is easiest to simply loop through their calendar events and match it up against a list of rooms.

The issue is: the naming convention for the rooms is spotty and they are located in several locations. Business has requested that I generate seperate reports for each location. Each location has several rooms. Originally I just pulled a list with the room names, and got it working, but since I now have to split it into locations, I need to pull a .csv with locations that correspond to the room...

I am not sure how to maintain the relation between the room name and location once I start looping the calendar events. I tried creating object items in the PSObject but obviously that isn't going to fly... Anyway, here is the code I have worked out so far:

```
$AllRooms = import-csv PathTo.csv
$Rooms = $AllRooms.DisplayName -join '|'

$Date = (Get-Date -Format yyMMddmm).ToString()
$ExportPath =  PathTo.csv
$max = (Get-Date).AddDays(7)
$min = Get-Date

$VIPS = Get-Content PathTo.txt 

$Info = ForEach($Vip in $VIPS) {

      foreach ($meeting in Get-CalendarDiagnosticObjects -Identity $VIP) {
        if ($meeting.Location -notmatch $Rooms) {
            continue
        }

        if ($meeting.StartTime.LocalTime -gt $max -or $meeting.StartTime.LocalTime -lt $min) {
            continue
        }


        $VIPName = Get-mailbox $VIP
        $DateStr = '{0:MM/dd}' -f $Meeting.StartTime.LocalTime
        $TimeStr = '{0:hh:mm tt}' -f $Meeting.StartTime.LocalTime
        [pscustomobject]@{
            VIP       = $VIPName
            Email     = $VIP
            Location  = $AllRooms.Office # This line doesn't work -This is where it all goes wrong
            Room      = $AllRooms.location # This line doesn't work -This is where it all goes wrong
            StartTime = $meeting.StartTime.LocalTime
            Date      = $DateStr
            Time      = $TimeStr
            TimeZone  = $meeting.TimeZone
        }
    }
} 
$UniqueInfo = $Info | Select-Object * -Unique | Where-Object { $_.Location -ne $null -and $_.StartTime -ne $null }
$UniqueInfo | Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

I know there are a lot of folks that would be thrilled if we can solve this. I have been all over Google etc and there is nothing simple that will allow for parsing rooms for recipients... So, even though this is backward, it should work, if I can get this last bit down. Thanks in advance, and may the Force be with you.